# For loop over trainControl(repeat) and than training knn model in this loop - caret

Tags: r, for-loop, r-caret, knn

my code only uses the first iteration and and dont know why exactly.
Do I have to save also ctrl in a vector or do I need the index variable i insert in the train function?

```
# Loading data and train and test split
data("iris")
index_train <- createDataPartition(y = iris$Species, p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
length(index_train)
trainset_iris <- iris[index_train,]
testset_iris <- iris[-index_train,]

# For loop
n <- 1:5
results <- rep(x = 0, times = length(n))
results
for ( i in 1:length(results) ) {
  ctrl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = i) # varying repeats
  knnFit <- train(Species ~ ., data = trainset_iris, method = "knn", trControl = ctrl, preProcess = 
                    c("center","scale"), tuneLength = 20)
  results[i] <- knnFit$bestTune
  results <- as.vector(results)
  print(results)
}
```

Thank you

Comment: The best thing would be to store each fit as an item in a list. If you want to keep it imperative, you could do "print debugging" at each point to see if the values of those control variables are what you assume.

Comment: Ty it worked. I added a list.